# versioning data in a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a database containing Questions and Tests (basically a list of questions). Teachers may create/update/delete questions and those can be used by any teacher to create tests.

Say Alice creates a question and Bob uses it for his test. If Alice comes back and modify her question, that would alter Bob's test, and Bob wouldn't like it.

To solve the problem, I'm thinking about adding a version number to the questions and use that as the primary key.

```
table Questions:
    version integer primary key
    id integer -- shared by the multiple revisions of the question
    owner integer

table Tests:
    id integer primary key
    owner integer

table Test_Questions:
    question integer references Questions ON DELETE RESTRICT
    test integer references Tests ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now, when Alice updates her question, a new row is created in the Questions table, and Bob's test stays unaltered. Nice, but now I have a problem with wasted space: I don't want to keep hundreds of revisions that are acutally referenced nowhere. So, when updating a question, I'd rather check if it is referenced anywhere, if so create a new revision, if not update in place.

I think the constraint "ON DELETE RESTRICT" might help me here: if my question is referenced anywhere, I won't be able to delete it, so I could try to delete it, and depending on the result reinsert it with the same revision number, or with a new one. But it feels wrong.

I guess my question is: **Is there a way to check if the ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint would be violated by a DELETE, so I could act accordingly depending on the result?** Something like a "dry run delete" of sorts?

Comment: A trigger cannot be applied to temp table only reference one, so really you need to test against a dummy data structure with some test data.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used the word trigger, as I was not referring to actual RDBMS "triggers". Rephrasing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the primary key on the `questions` table on `(id, version)`, right?

That would require that you have both columns in `test_questions`.

About getting rid of old question versions, I would do the following:

- Whenever a new question version is added, try to delete all other versions of the same question.
- Catch and ignore any errors of class `foreign_key_violation` (SQLSTATE `23503`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! 

regarding the primary key, I could have the primary key on (id, version), but it is not necessary in my case.